# How can I start activity inside frame?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a custom tabbar with scrolling tabbar items.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tabbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_rlTopbar" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/bottombar" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_llTabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
...
        m_scrollTabbar = new HScrollTabbar(this, R.id.main_tabcontent, R.id.main_llTabs);
        m_scrollTabbar.addTab(null, 0, HomeActivity.class, true);
...
```

hscrolltabbar.java

```
public class HScrollTabbar {
    private int m_nTabContentId = -1;
    private int m_nScrollTabbarId = -1;
    private Activity m_activityParent = null;
    private ArrayList<ButtonTabbarItem> m_aryTabButton = new ArrayList<ButtonTabbarItem>();

    private int m_nSelectedIndex =  -1;

    public void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
        LinearLayout llTabs = (LinearLayout) m_activityParent.findViewById(m_nScrollTabbarId);
        ButtonTabbarItem item = new ButtonTabbarItem(m_activityParent, c, m_aryTabButton.size());
        llTabs.addView(item);
        m_aryTabButton.add(item);
        if (m_aryTabButton.size() == 1) {
            setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
        item.setOnSelectTabListener(onSelectTabListener);
    }

    private OnSelectTabListener onSelectTabListener = new OnSelectTabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelect(int nSelectedIndex) {
            setSelectedIndex(nSelectedIndex);
        }
    };

    public void setSelectedIndex(int nIndex) {
        if (m_nSelectedIndex == nIndex)
            return;
        ButtonTabbarItem item = null;
        if (m_nSelectedIndex > -1) {
            item = m_aryTabButton.get(m_nSelectedIndex);
            item.setSelected(false);
        }
        m_nSelectedIndex = nIndex;
        item = m_aryTabButton.get(m_nSelectedIndex);
        item.setSelected(true);

            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) m_activityParent.findViewById(m_nTabContentId);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(frame.getContext(), item.getClassTarget());
            frame.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
    public int getSelectedIndex() {
        return m_nSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

buttontabbaritem.java

```
public class ButtonTabbarItem extends FrameLayout {
    private static final int TAB_BTN_TAG = 100;
    private Class<?> m_classTarget;
    OnSelectTabListener m_listener = null;

    public ButtonTabbarItem(Context context, Class<?> classTarget, int nIndex) {
        super(context);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hscroll_tabbar_item, layout);
        addView(view);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hscroll_tabbar_item_btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(onClickTab);
        btn.setTag(TAB_BTN_TAG + nIndex);

        m_classTarget = classTarget;
    }
    public Class<?> getClassTarget() {
        return m_classTarget;
    }
    public void setClassTarget(Class<?> classTarget) {
        m_classTarget = classTarget;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean bSelected) {
        if (bSelected) {
        } else {
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener onClickTab = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (m_listener != null)
                m_listener.onSelect((Integer) v.getTag() - TAB_BTN_TAG);
        }
    };

    public interface OnSelectTabListener {
        public void onSelect(int nSelectedIndex);
    }

    public void setOnSelectTabListener(OnSelectTabListener listener) {
        m_listener = listener;
    }

}



FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) m_activityParent.findViewById(m_nTabContentId);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(frame.getContext(), item.getClassTarget());
            frame.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

I'm trying to start activity inside frame, but it's not work.
Please help me.

Comment: any error.. or simply not showing...?? If error, show some logcat lines...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You can't easily start an activity "within" a view. If that's what you want, look at [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead.